# MediaElement.NaturalDuration throws exception when querying TimeSpan.TotalSeconds

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, mediaelement

I have a winforms form in which I use a MediaElement. Everything is working (more or less) perfectly. The only thing is, after loading a media file (mp3) accessing `NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` throws an exception

> InvalidOperatoinException: A TimeSpan property can not be returned for a duration value of automatic.

(Translated from german by myself)

How can I access the timespan property? There is no special setting used in all the examples I have found (ok, they seem to be WPF native...)

I am using VisualStudio Express .Net 4, C# on Windows 7.

Any hints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to wait for `MediaOpened` event to fire, `NaturalDuration` will be available after that. To check if value is available, you can use `NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan` property.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! It is even stated in the documentation for NaturalDuration... hindsight...

Comment: mediaElement1.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement1_MediaOpened);  void mediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Duration d = mediaElement1.NaturalDuration;
        }

Comment: @Discord I am having the same problem. The weird thing about it is that I get the Duration at the end of Player_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) ?! How can I fix it then ?