# Issue with getting the duration of an audio file using the MediaPlayer class

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player, duration

I'm working with some Audio files in my app (mp3, wav, ..etc)
I was using the MediaPlayer class from the `System.Windows.Media` namespace..
but I had some problems with computing the duration of the sound file, 
my form is actually a small media player, it has a `TrackBar` a `ComboBox`
and the normal `next`, `previous` and `play` buttons ..
I used this code to get the duration of the sound file to determine the maximum value of the track bar:

```
private void MusicComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
  System.Windows.Duration duration = Player.NaturalDuration;
  SeekBar.Value = 0;
  Player.Open(new Uri(soundEffectPackage.GetMusicAt(MusicComboBox.SelectedIndex)));
  if(duration.HasTimeSpan)
    SeekBar.Maximum = duration.TimeSpan.Seconds;  
}
```

This is working fine with only some of the files, 
while other files don't have a `TimeSpan` so the if isn't getting executed, and if i removed the if, I'll get an exception saying that I should check first to see if the `HasTimeSpan` is true, then moving on.

How can i fix this?
How can i get the duration of the audio file ?
And what do they mean by a time span ?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068332/mediaelement-naturalduration-throws-excpetion-when-queriyng-timespan-totalsecond)

You need to wait for MediaOpened event to fire, NaturalDuration will be available after that. To check if value is available, you can use `NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan` property.

but the best chose for working with audio and video file is "Fmod.dll".this have a lot of Privilege to work with audio file

Comment: you're welcome,i already used fmod dll it have a lot of option and very interesting to work with audio and video file,if you have problem i will help you.